# Plotting array of x and y values as points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I can't understand this: when I write the following code I obtain this graph in matlab.

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5];
y = [0 1 0 1 0 1];
figure
plot(x,y);
```

[image]

I had just expected that only the points written in arrays x and y would be plotted ,but the graph shows lines also...
I can't understand why is it so... Please help where am I wrong

Comment: That's how `plot` works by default: it joins the points with straight lines. Try `plot(x,y,'o')` or `stem(x,y)`

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that the desired plot is often called a "scatterplot" en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot - Matlab offers a dediacted plot command for those scatter plots: scatter(x, y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the following

```
figure(10);
plot(x,y, '.');

figure(20);
plot(x,y, 'x');

figure(30);
plot(x,y, '-r');
```

See the differences... a dot-scatter, x-scatter and red line plot.

In the [plot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec) documentation you can read more about line styles. By default it is a blue line, as you can see in your plot!